# FadeIn and FadeOut effects with multiple set of images in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, frontend

I want to fade In/Out some set of images in my web page, just like
http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/450/
But there are certain conditions which are :
1. When I click any one of the image, new set of images should replace all of them with fade effects (similar to a "not a robot" captcha)
2. I want to know which image was clicked, in my back-end
How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var activeId = $(".active").each(function(){
    $("#content" + $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","")).show(1000);
    });

    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
        var $tabs =$(this).closest(".tabs"); 
        $("#content" +$tabs.attr("data-lastContent")).hide(1000);
        $(this).closest(".tabs").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
        $tabs.attr("data-lastContent", id);
        $("#content" + id).show(1000);     
    });
});
```